# Unexpected output using reduce to create json

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, reduce

I'm working with apps script. I have an array of objects 'sendableRows' that I would like to turn to json and email. an object looks like:

```
[{Phone Number=14444444444, Eagerness=High, Index=4816.0, completed=, Lot Size=0.74, Power or water=, campaign=, absoluteRow=84.0}]
```

my code:

```
const json = sendableRows.reduce(row => JSON.stringify(row), "")

Logger.log(json);

MailApp.sendEmail({
to: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
subject: todayString,
htmlBody: json
});
```

unfortunately 'json' is being output as:

```
[20-07-26 20:07:55:244 EDT] "\"\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\\\\\"\\\"\""
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The "object" syntax is wrong, the code isn't complete. Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```js
const json = JSON.stringify(sendableRows);
```