# Adding Spaces to HTML email with apps script using reduce

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, mapreduce

I'm working with apps script. I have an array of objects 'sendableRows' that I would like to turn to json add a space between each line in the email body (I figured a 
 tag because the body is html). An object looks like:

```
{Phone Number=14444444444, , Index=4816.0, completed=, Lot Size=0.74, Power or water=, campaign=, absoluteRow=84.0 , ....}
```

my code:

```
const json = sendableRows.reduce(row => JSON.stringify(row), "")

Logger.log(json);

MailApp.sendEmail({
to: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
subject: todayString,
htmlBody: json
});
```

unfortunately 'json' is being output as (sorry, the properties don't match exactly as I've truncated different ones for the object and the output):

```
 "\"{\\\"Index\\\":4877,\\\"Email\\\":\\\"ccccc@yahoo.com\\\",\\\"Phone Number\\\":\\\"1234567890\\\",Asking\\\":14651.13,\\\"New Asking\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"Assessed\\\":28890,\\\"campaign\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"completed\\\":\\\"\\\",\\\"last_contacted\\\":\\\"2020-07-27T16:20:31.898Z\\\",\\\"relativeRow\\\":64,\\\"absoluteRow\\\":67}<br>\"<br>"<br>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the output you expect is like `['json_string_for_one_element' + '<br>' + 'json_string_for_one_element' + '<br>' + ...]` ?

Comment: anyway, the usage `sendableRows.reduce(row => JSON.stringify(row), "")` is wrong, because the first parameter of the reducer function is the **Accumulator**, not current element, it should be like `sendableRows.reduce((pre, row) => pre +JSON.stringify(row), "")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected output using reduce to create json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63107142/unexpected-output-using-reduce-to-create-json)

Comment: Thank you - I used     var json = sendableRows.reduce((pre, row) => pre +JSON.stringify(row)+"<br><br>", "") - still getting used to arrow notation since apps script now supports it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
to: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
subject: todayString,
htmlBody: JSON.stringify(json, null, 2)
});
```

Comment: Thank you , I ended up using     var json = sendableRows.reduce((pre, row) => pre +JSON.stringify(row)+"<br><br>", "")

Comment: I would like to accept @Sphinx 's answer but its not entered as an answer, only a comment.